# How to scale a Image of kivy toggle button and keep its aspect ratio?

Tags: python, button, scale, kivy

Hej

I want to create my own radio button in kivy. For that I am using a template:

```
<myCheckBox@ToggleButton>:
    background_normal: 'gfx/cbActive.png'
    background_down: 'gfx/cbInactive.png'    
    background_disabled_down: 'gfx/cbActive.png'
    background_disabled_normal: 'gfx/cbInactive.png'
```

The button looks like:

[image: Button not scaled]

When using the template at the App it can be downscaled but the downscale process does not scale it symmetrically. It looks like:

[image: bad scaled image]

Any ideas on why the downscaling isn't symmetrical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style for `Button` (and `ToggleButton`) uses a `BorderImage` to scale the background. This allows the standard button-type images to be used appropriately. But you can easily disable this behavior by setting the [border property](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html#kivy.uix.button.Button.border) used for scaling:

```
<myCheckBox@ToggleButton>:
    border: 0, 0, 0, 0
    background_normal: 'gfx/cbActive.png'
    background_down: 'gfx/cbInactive.png'    
    background_disabled_down: 'gfx/cbActive.png'
    background_disabled_normal: 'gfx/cbInactive.png'
```

Comment: This problem should be fixed at the new version. The fix is still on github [http://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/3165](http://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/3165)

Comment: Thanks! saved my day :)